# How do you prove $\frac{u}{v} < \frac{z}{w} \implies \frac{u+z}{v+w} < \frac{z}{w}$

Tags: inequality

The bounds for the variables are $\forall u,v,w,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$

What I've got so far:

$\frac{u}{v} < \frac{z}{w}$

$\frac{u}{v+w} < \frac{z}{w}$

I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: From $uw<zv$ it follows $uw+zw<zv+zw$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given is $\frac uv<\frac zw$, which we can write as $uw<vz$. Now add $zw$ to both sides: $$uw+wz<vz+wz$$ and thus 
$$(u+z)w<(v+w)z$$
Which we can write to
$$\frac{u+z}{v+w}<\frac zw$$
It's worth noting that we can do all this multiplying and dividing on both sides because $u,v,w,z$ are positive.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{u+z}{v+w} < \dfrac{z}{w} \Longleftrightarrow w(u+z) < z(v+w) \Longleftrightarrow uw+zw< zv+zw\Longleftrightarrow uw <zv\Longleftrightarrow\dfrac{u}{v}<\dfrac{z}{w}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{u+z}{v+w} < \frac{z}{w}\iff \dfrac{uw+zw}{w(v+w)}< \frac{vz+wz}{w(v+w)} \iff uw+zw<vz+wz\iff uw<vz$$ which holds if and only if

$$uw<vz\iff \frac{uw}{vw} < \frac{zv}{wv} \iff \frac{u}{v} < \frac{z}{w}.$$